# jQuery Datatable - changing data url

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently using the jQuery Datatables plugin.

I now need to be able to change the ajax data source based on some form input values, which would be submitted on a button click?

What is the recommended method for achieving this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnReport')
            .click(function () {
                var table = $('#reports').DataTable();
                table.ajax.reload();
            });

        var querystring = '?from=' + $('#datetimepickerFrom').val() + '&till='  $('#datetimepickerFrom').val();

        var url = '/api/reports/custom';

        var table = $("#reports").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: url + queryString,
                dataSrc : ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "fullName"
                },
                {
                    data: "timeIn"
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ajax.url()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) and [`ajax.url().load()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()) to set URL for the table and load data from that URL.

For example:

```
function getDataTableUrl(){
    return 
        '?from=' + $('#datetimepickerFrom').val() 
        + '&till=' +  $('#datetimepickerFrom').val();
}

$('#btnReport')
    .click(function () {
        var table = $('#reports').DataTable();
        table.ajax.url(getDataTableUrl()).load(); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I needed

Comment: @adnan, there was error in the code which is corrected.

Comment: A slightly more flexible and efficient approach to the above (assuming you may well need thse values for the initial request as well) would be to put the `getDataTableUrl()` function call into the data table initialisation e.g. `ajax : { url : getDataTableUrl() }`  and then call `table.ajax.reload()` wherever you need to reload