# configure datatables but call ajax after filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

My question is simmilar to this: [jQuery Datatable - changing data url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38435300/777551) but I don't want to make the ajax call while setting the datatable

I have this setting for the datatable:

```
p._createDataTableMappings = function (application, field) {
        $('#data_mappings').DataTable({
            "dom": 'rtip',
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/api/applications/" + application + "/mappings/" + field,
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Application1" }, 
                { "data": "Field1" },
                { "data": "Value1" },
                { "data": "Application2" },
                { "data": "Field2" },
                { "data": "Value2" }
            ]
        });
```

The data returned by the url is an array of objects, so I put the dataSrc to ""

But I don't want to make the ajax call until *application* and *field* values have data. These values are set from this function:

```
$("#search").on("click", function (event) {
    var application_value = $("#application").val();
    var field_value = $("#field").val();
    if (application_value && field_value) {
        var table = $("#data_mappings").DataTable();
        table.ajax.url("/api/applications/" + application_value + "/mappings/" + field_value).load();
    }
});
```

My doubt is how to configure the ajax call

```
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/applications/" + application + "/mappings/" + field,
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
```

- If I remove the url property I get a warning from datatables saying: Invalid JSON response
- If I remove the entire ajax property in the setting function, calling `table.ajax.url(myUrl).load()` expects an object with a property named data, but I have an array of objects.

Comment: I think it's not as easy as changing the url parameter.. The plugin is also doing some caching I guess.. You should rather call `table.fnDestroy();` and then you re-init your Datatables with new ajax url. Also check this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049783/1151408)

Answer (score 1):

As @Yuri said, the best way is probably to destroy the table and rebuild it. This [live example](http://live.datatables.net/vejupiva/1/edit) may help - you press a button to load the data, so this would be analogous to your click event.